# Fastlane import_certificate could not find file

Tags: ios, ruby, continuous-integration, fastlane, github-actions

I am trying to execute a lane on Github action.

I have this lane :

```
lane :debug do |values|

    create_keychain(
      name: "Keychain",
      default_keychain: true,
      unlock: true,
      timeout: 3600,
      lock_when_sleeps: true,
      password: "Password"
    )

    puts `ls -ll`
    puts `pwd`

    import_certificate(
      keychain_name: "Keychain",
      certificate_path: "CERTIFICATE_DEV.cer"
    )
```

Command `ls -ll` return this :

[image]

And `import_certificate()` fail with this error message :

```
[14:10:24]: --------------------------------
[14:10:24]: --- Step: import_certificate ---
[14:10:24]: --------------------------------
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                  Lane Context                                   |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM          | ios                                                 |
| PLATFORM_NAME             | ios                                                 |
| LANE_NAME                 | ios debug                                           |
| ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_KEYCHAIN | "/Users/runner/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db" |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
[14:10:24]: Could not find file 'CERTIFICATE_DEV.cer'
```

What can i do to import my certificate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, file paths can be tricky in `fastlane`. I suggest that you pass the absolute path of the certificate.

```
import_certificate(
  keychain_name: "Keychain",
  certificate_path: File.absolute_path("CERTIFICATE_DEV.cer")
)
```